# SwiftUI View Reloads When Exiting Fullscreen of AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swiftui, video-streaming, avplayer

I have this custom Video Player.

`struct FullscreenVideoPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

```
@Binding var player: AVQueuePlayer
```

//    var videoURL: URL

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player
    controller.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
    controller.exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true

    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    // Update the controller if needed
}
```

}`

I call it like such:

`                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
ForEach(videos[channel]?.indices ?? [].indices) { i in

```
                        if i == current_playing {
                            FullscreenVideoPlayer(player: $player)
                                .frame(width: VIDEO_WIDTH, height: VIDEO_HEIGHT)
                                .padding(0)
                        } else {
                            VideoLoadingView()
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .modifier(ScrollingHStackModifier(items: vids.count, itemWidth: VIDEO_WIDTH, itemSpacing: 0, current: $current_playing))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)`
```

And I have these variables:

`    var videos: [Channel : [Video]]
var channel: Channel

```
@Binding var current_playing: Int

@State var player = AVQueuePlayer()
@State var removedItems: [AVPlayerItem] = []`
```

When I exit full screen play, the screen reloads all the videos and requeries the data. As you can imagine this creates a frustrating user experience and huge bandwidth issue. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Dealing with the same issue now.

Comment: Same here, were you able to find a solution for this problem?